# How to get all the names in dropzone in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having difficulty on getting all the file name I dropped; I only get the first dropped item name but I needed all the names so i can upload it all. Here is the sample of my dropzone:

```
onDrop(acceptedFiles) {
    debugger
    console.log('Received files: ', acceptedFiles);
    this.setState({files: acceptedFiles});
    let {form} = this.props.timeline;       

        acceptedFiles.map(file =>  { 
            form.Name=file.name
        });

}
```

and here is what happens in the dropzone debugged 
[image]

Comment: The problem with your example is that you map through the `acceptedFiles` and then you assign the form.name again for each item. This will result that your `form.Name` will always be the same as the last item's name in the `acceptedFiles` collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `acceptedFiles` already contains all the filenames but the filename is encapsulated inside the object which also seems to contain the `TimelineKey`as well.

If you only want the filenames then you need to modify your code a bit:

`const filenames = acceptedFiles.map(file => (file.name))`

Then you have the collection of filenames and you can do what ever you want with it.

Comment: Yes, it will be a collection of names.